# How to resize the text's width accordingly to the image responsive width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to the html5/css3 and bootstrap world since I started to learn these things one week ago.

My problem is that I want the text width (the area's width in which the text is displayed) to be accordingly with the width of the responsive image.
When the page is in lg/md/sm responsive mode, the text is displayed correctly under the image accordingly to "its width" but when in xs responsive mode, the text is not displayed correctly.

Image of what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OVjf.jpg

Images (the link has to images, switch with keyboard's keys!) of your proposed solution (the problem is still there!):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj6Ji.png

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header" id="p-h-1">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col xm-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
        <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
        <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col xm-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure><img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col xm-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure><img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea guys?

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language and sorry if my question has been answered over and over again but I don't know which keywords to search for...

I found this solution working for me (still I need to know the image size to add fixed width to the

element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header" id="p-h-1">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
        <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
        <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure><img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure><img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  p {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid black 1px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /* Based on figure width */
    width: 430px;
  }
}
```

Comment: *but when in xs responsive mode, the text is not displayed correctly.* Not sure what is not displayed. I can see it properly from here.

Comment: I attached an image to explain better what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the grid to `col-xs-6` and apply offset with `col-xs-offset-3`

**Output:**

[image]

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  p {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header" id="p-h-1">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive center-block" />
      </figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous
        tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive center-block" />
      </figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous
        tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive center-block" />
      </figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous
        tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but this is not what I real wanted because:
- the padding added is dynamic after the page enters xs mode, I want it to be static/fixed padding according to the image static/fixed width in xs mode.
- I don't know the image sizes, it would be nice if there was a solution that takes into account this.

Comment: I meant the opposite: the padding added it's fixed but I want it to be dynamic because the image width it's fixed while the text width isn't

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, your solution works! Still I would like to copy this site's behavior, can you help me? I mean with the text not changing lines etc but being static
http://www.metid.polimi.it/

Comment: But it doesn't use Bootstrap and has a fixed width. This solution is the same as that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw an error in the management of the grid is written with `col xm-12` that is not a class bootstrap3 instead of 'with-xs-as`

prova con queste classi

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header" id="p-h-1">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
        <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
        <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure><img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <figure><img src="images/prova.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></figure>
      <h3 class="text-center">Prova</h3>
      <p>The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed the code error but the problem is still there

Comment: the css `img-responsive  center-block` what's contain?

Comment: An image with width: 440px, height: 270px but it's just a sample image, I don't know the real size of the images I will put there

Comment: I'm not asking about the image size, but the css class.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, here is the css:
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

Comment: while .img-responsive {   
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}